# Can someone confirm if this theory is correct? - Javascript & Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, var

I am learning javascript and really just started - I am using the Firebug Extension in Firefox to try out  a few things.

I have set up 2 var(iables) and the 2nd one uses values from the first one:

```
var multipleValues =  [10,20,30,40,50] ;
var reverse = multipleValues.reverse();`
```

Now I want to pull data from that array via an if statement and create an alert like so:

```
if (multipleValues [1] == 20) {
alert("Value is there.");
}
else {
alert("Value is not there");
}
```

Now here is my question - How come when I run the code like this it gives me the "else" option, but when I comment out the `var reverse` it comes up as correct?

I thought because I had declared the variable at the start I can access it later on, however using the reverse option seems to be canceling it out?? Am I misunderstanding the theory??

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `reverse` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) modifies the array in place (while also returning the array). Try something like this instead:

```
var reversed = multipleValues.slice(0).reverse();
```

Comment: Yup that gives me both options:-) I going to look into the slice option now too - just so I learn to understand it:-)

Answer (score 2):

`reverse()` reverses the array in place.

```
var x = [1,2,3];
x.reverse();
console.log(x); //Now returns [3,2,1]
```

So, rather than leaving the original array unmodified, it reverses it. It **also** returns the value of the reversed array, so both `multipleValues` and `reverse` are set to the reversed value.

JavaScript can be inconsistent. Some native methods do not modify the caller, and instead return the value (Like, say, `String.prototype.split`). Some native methods *only* modify the caller and don't return a relevant value (`Array.prototype.splice` is an example). Some native methods, like this one, `Array.prototype.reverse`, do both.

One reliable way to know which does what is to read documentation; I recommend [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), which describes `reverse()` as such:

> The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object
>   in place, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array.

Answer (score 2):

[Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is destructive and changes the original array.  It also returns a reference to the array so the two objects should be equal to each other.

Comment: You where first - I was amazed with the quick answers:-)
This makes complete sense:-)